# Problems with permalinks (.htaccess not working)

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, htaccess

I would like to use permalinks but they are not working. Whenever I use permanlinks like /%postname*/ are something else that differs from the default ... I get an 404-error.

Calling php_info I can see that Loaded Modules contains mod_rewrite.

```
# BEGIN Better WP Security
Options -Indexes

<files .htaccess>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</files>

<files readme.html>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</files>

<files readme.txt>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</files>

<files install.php>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</files>

<files wp-config.php>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)wp-includes/ms-files.php
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(bash|git|hg|log|svn|swp|cvs) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>|ê|"|;|\?|\*|=$).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*("|'|<|>|\|{||).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%0|%A|%B|%C|%D|%E|%F|127\.0).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|select|concat|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loggedout=true
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

</IfModule>
# END Better WP Security

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Whenever I change the permalink-structure a 404error occurs. The apache's error_log shows no errors regarding this problem.

The OS is an Suse Linux. Apache/2.2.12.

In the httpd.conf there are the following relevant entries:

```
# forbid access to the entire filesystem by default
<Directory /srv/www/htdocs>
      Options +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory />
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

# use .htaccess files for overriding,
AccessFileName .htaccess
# and never show them
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Does someone know what I could check to get the permalinks running? I cannot find out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a virtual host whose document root is different from the global document root set in httpd.conf?  If so, you'll want to specify Directory rules for that other location to include AllowOverride.

Comment: We are not using a virtual host. Is there maybe something wrong with the sort order of some entries? Unfortunately I have no glue.

Comment: It doesn't appear that there's any <files> directive for index.php, and based on the <Directory> directives you have set it will be denied.  Perhaps add a <files> directive to allow access to index.php